# How to perform JOIN and only use single record for each instance on 2nd table

Tags: sql-server, join

I am trying to perform a join from table 1.  In table 2 there could be multiple matches on the join, but I only want to use each match once and only once.  How do I do this?  Here is my data set:

```
Products

Product_Plan_ID      Product_Plan_Creation_Date
===============      =========================
123-3241             1/2/2018
123-3242             1/15/2018
123-3242             1/17/2018
123-3243             1/18/2018
123-3244             2/2/2018
123-3245             2/5/2018
```

AND...

```
Product_Delivery

Product_Plan_ID      Product_Plan_Delivery_Date
===============      =====================
123-3242             1/20/2018
123-3242             1/22/2018
```

Here is code to generate tables and data set...

```
CREATE TABLE Products
(
Product_Plan_ID varchar(25),
Product_Plan_Creation_Date date
)

create table Product_Delivery
(
Product_Plan_ID varchar(25),
Product_Plan_Delivery_Date date
)

INSERT INTO Products 
select '123-3241', '1/2/2018'
union all
select '123-3242', '1/15/2018'
union all
select '123-3242', '1/17/2018'
union all
select '123-3243', '1/18/2018'
union all
select '123-3244', '2/2/2018'
union all
select '123-3245', '2/5/2018'

INSERT INTO Product_Delivery
SELECT '123-3242', '1/20/2018'
UNION ALL
SELECT '123-3242', '1/22/2018'
```

In my query, I want to join the Products table to Product_Delivery and for each row in Products, I want to join it to Product_Delivery matching on the Product_Plan_ID and where the Product_Plan_Delivery_Date is within 30 days of the Product_Plan_Creation_Date.  The kicker is, if I find a match in Product_Delivery, I only want that match to be used a single time.  The way I have it now, I'm ending up with duplicates on Product_Plan_Delivery_Date 1/20/2018 below.  Here's my query so far:

```
select Products.Product_Plan_ID, Products.Product_Plan_Creation_Date, 
t2.Product_Plan_Delivery_Date from Products
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 t.Product_Plan_ID, t.Product_Plan_Delivery_Date 
    FROM Product_Delivery t
    where t.Product_Plan_Delivery_Date between 
    Products.Product_Plan_Creation_Date and dateadd(dd, 30, Products.Product_Plan_Creation_Date)
and Products.Product_Plan_ID = t.Product_Plan_ID
) t2
```

The problem with the above is I end up with a duplicate match for Product_Plan_ID 123-3242 on Product_Plan_Delivery_Date, 1/20/2018.  How would I write this so I have Product_Plan_ID 123-3242 match first on 1/20/2018, then 2nd on 1/22/2018?

My desired result set would be this:

```
Product_Plan_ID    Product_Plan_Creation_Date    Product_Plan_Delivery_Date
123-3242           1/15/2018                     1/20/2018
123-3242           1/17/2018                     1/22/2018
```

However...I'm getting this:

```
Product_Plan_ID    Product_Plan_Creation_Date    Product_Plan_Delivery_Date
123-3242           1/15/2018                     1/20/2018
123-3242           1/17/2018                     1/20/2018
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why type `dd` instead of `day`? Also, be very careful about regional dates like `m/d/y`. Much better to use unambiguous formats like `yyyymmdd`. And finally, `BETWEEN` is ok here, I recommend against it for date/range queries in general. See [this](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Will keep in mind.  I guess, I just always learned "dd" for day, so have always used that.

Answer (score 2):

For future posts, it is better to provide `CREATE TABLE` statements and `INSERT` statements. It is also beneficial to add an expected result set. What I guess you are trying to do is to pair Product_Plan_Creation_Date and Product_Plan_Delivery_Date. You can create an ordering number with a `WINDOW` function:

```
SELECT Product_Plan_ID, Product_Plan_Creation_Date
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Plan_ID
                          ORDER BY Product_Plan_Creation_Date) AS RN
FROM Products
```

and similar for Product_Delivery:

```
SELECT Product_Plan_ID, Product_Plan_Delivery_Date
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Plan_ID
                          ORDER BY Product_Plan_Delivery_Date) AS RN
FROM Product_Delivery
```

Now you can use the ordering number to join these two derived tables:

```
SELECT A.Product_Plan_ID, A.Product_Plan_Creation_Date
     , B.Product_Plan_Delivery_Date
FROM (
    SELECT Product_Plan_ID, Product_Plan_Creation_Date
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Plan_ID
                              ORDER BY Product_Plan_Creation_Date) AS RN
    FROM Products
) AS A
JOIN (
    SELECT Product_Plan_ID, Product_Plan_Delivery_Date
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product_Plan_ID
                          ORDER BY Product_Plan_Delivery_Date) AS RN
    FROM Product_Delivery
) AS B
    ON A.Product_Plan_ID = B.Product_Plan_ID
    AND A.RN = B.RN
```

Comment: This is a good start, but it's missing criteria to limit matches to 30 days.

Comment: ... which will probably require a recursive CTE (or maybe two cursors!)

Comment: Yes, thank you for the prompt responses.  I've revised my original query, to include the CREATE and INSERT statement as well as corrected the query to include the limit match on 30 days.  Thank you everyone.

Comment: I see I missed the 30 day requirement. What should the effect be if say the 2:nd rows are more than 30 days apart? Should they both be skipped or should they be paired with another row that lies within 30 days?

Comment: It should just be one for one match.  So, if one row is within 30 days, then they should match.  If the 2nd row of the same Product_Plan_ID is outside the 30 days, then it should skip that one.

Comment: If the next row is not within 30 days, the one after that won't be either. :-)

Comment: Not sure how I should rephrase myself, what I'm after is whether it is possible to first enumerate and then apply a 30-day predicate on the enumerated sets.  Using pseudo dates for A = {1,31} and B = {32,35} we would end up with {(31,35)} if enumeration is applied first and {(31,32)} if the 30-day predicate is applied first.